# Is it possible to apply multithreading in consolemenu based UI in Python? How?

Tags: python-3.x

I have written an UI using consolemenu in python. Is multithreading be implemented in the code? if so How?

Comment: What does "apply multithreading" mean?

Comment: Concurrency (or parallelism for that matter) should not be your goal. It should be the MEANS to achieve your goal. Is there anything wrong with your code?

Comment: No. Nothing wrong with the code. You might know any console menu based UI in python. now if you want to apply multithreading for the submenu items. Will you be able to apply?